# Collatz conjecture and related problems - mathematical machinery

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, open-problem, collatz-conjecture

Collatz conjecture stands as an open problem. That leads me to believe that the conjecture cannot be resolved by elementary means.

Which brings me to my question: What techniques/machinery from number theory are well suited for studying Collatz sequences/Collatz conjecture (and related problems)?

Comment: if you don't think it can be solved with elementary means why is the question tagged elementary-number-theory?

Comment: By elementary - I meant no knowledge of number theory of any kind.

Comment: My understanding is that the problem is that the answer to your question is "none." There is no machinery yet. You may try reading Jeff Lagarias's paper on this, which is at a good rigorous mathematical level. http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lagarias/

Comment: A list of topics/ideas that have been brought to bear would be a list of ideas that didn't work, and whose relatives probably don't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I found this blog by Tao very interesting:

[Terence Tao on Collatz](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/)

Comment: Dear N.S. : Any statements that are "not an answer... but interesting" are better candidates for comments than solutions.

Comment: @rschwieb I know this, but most of the comments are ignored/missed and I think that any non-expert interested in Collatz should read that blog. Probably the best solution is to make the answer a Wiki, how can one do that?

Comment: I don't mind too much either way: it was just a suggestion. Actually I'd rather see this out of the unanswered queue with this solution than see it unanswered :)